# Launch modal popup extender when button is pressed

Tags: asp.net

I have a button setup to export my gridviews to word.  Everything works fine, except I cannot find a way to launch/cancel my `modalpopupextender` I use to show that processing is happening. If I add it the button click:
   `btnExportToWord.Attributes.Add("onclick", "StartProgressBarNoValid()")` it does not canel the `modalpopupextender`

Here is the update panel and the javascript function I use.

```
 function StartProgressBarNoValid() {
     var myExtender = $find('ProgressBarModalPopupExtender');
     ProgressImg = document.getElementById('MyImage');
     setTimeout("ProgressImg.src = ProgressImg.src", 10);
     myExtender.show();
     return true;
 }

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"> 
    <ContentTemplate> 
        <div> 
            <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ProgressBarModalPopupExtender" runat="server"
            backgroundCssClass="ModalBackground" behaviorID="ProgressBarModalPopupExtender" 
            TargetControlID="hiddenField1" PopupControlID="Panel1" />
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Style="display: none; background-color: #C0C0C0;"> 
                    <img id="MyImage" src="../Images/Vista_Searching_Bar.gif" alt="" />
                    <div id="processMessage" style="width:200px;" ><br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp; Loading...<br /><br />
                    </div>
                </asp:Panel> 
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
        </div> 
    </ContentTemplate> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

what is wrong with  `ProgressBarModalPopupExtender.Show()`  and `ProgressBarModalPopupExtender.Hide()`  from the codebehind?

Comment: Not sure why, but the ProgressBarModalPopupExtender.Show() will not execute on the codebehind button click.

Comment: it should, I heavily use it on my legacy projects and they work just fine. Why do you say it doesn't? Do you get any error?

Comment: I am not gettting any errors.  Here is the button click event I am using.

Comment: Sorry cannot add the code.  I am calling other functions and attaching a stylesheet to the export.  But nothing out of the ordinary.